# Ubuntu installation says /home has 0MB of space when allocated 50GB

Tags: system-installation, disk-usage

I've assigned the following space to these partitions:

```
sda1 500MB (efi)
sda2 50000MB (ext4)     /home
sda2 25000MB (ext4)     /
```

Some error comes up, we’re reporting it to the devs, click through that, unable to report:

> Your home partition has less that 0MB of free space

I’ve tried a million different things, wiping drive, unplugging all other drives, using a different drive, nothing works. Any idea why?

Edit: Just tried again and now I can’t click through the select keyboard screen, it comes up with

> ubi-console-setup failed with exit code 1

Comment: If you try to add an image and it doesn't work but does give you a link, you can include the link and someone can edit the post to expand it into an image. If you can't submit your [edit] with a link, you could post a comment with the link. Either way, if you have a link to an image and you reply to this comment by posting a comment with `@EliahKagan` in it, I'll be notified and I'll help if I can. (In addition, if you believe you've found a bug in the Ask Ubuntu interface--that is, that it's not working as it is intended to work--and you want to report it, you can do so by posting on [meta].)